# PHP html tag finding

Tags: php, search, tags, design-patterns

Any one can help me in finding any tag present in text as html format.

Ex:  `$text="<a href>the hero</a>";`

find "`<a`" is present in `$text` or not in php.

Comment: You want to know if there are tags in your string? remove the tags? or know which tags are there? Depending on your answer, the real answer will be different

Comment: Somewhat to the point: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: I want to check "<a" is present or not

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to check for the presence of "<a" in a string use strpos. It is much faster than preg_* which must first compile a regular expression.

```
<?php
$exists = (strpos($text , '<a') !== false);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For parsing HTML is best to use some kind of DOM parser, more info here: [PHP HTML DOM Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330545/php-html-dom-parser), but if your goal is only to check existence of html tag, `preg_match` can be the solution:

```
$text="<a href>the hero</a>";
var_dump(preg_match("/\<a.*\>(.*?)\<\/a\>/si", $text));
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe:

```
if(str_replace("<a", "<a", $text)) {
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "not ok";
}
```

See [the manual for `str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace).

Comment: You are doing unnecessarily job using `str_replace` - replacing string with the same string. Using such construction decreases code readability.