# Regex match url without <a> tag - JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regex expression in JavaScript for the same use case as this post here: [regex matching links without <a> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651869/regex-matching-links-without-a-tag)

My goal is to transform a string such as

```
Here is a link https://www.somewebsite.com/ here is a link already in an a tag <a href="https://www.somewebsite.com/">https://www.somewebsite.com/</a>
```

To

```
Here is a link <a href="https://www.somewebsite.com/">https://www.somewebsite.com/</a> here is a link already in an a tag <a href="https://www.somewebsite.com/">https://www.somewebsite.com/</a>
```

There are many regex examples for a url, but I am not sure how to add an "and" condition for the url match not being in an `<a>` tag. I have only found examples so far for php or python, but not JS.

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links

Comment: This is an example why parsing HTML with reg exp is a bad idea.

Comment: "I am not sure how to `add` an and condition" - you could use a negitive look ahead to confirm that the matched pattern (the link) in not followed by a `</a>` tag. Another approach would be to use a negated character set to tell the regex engine to match everything until a `<` is encountered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using regex, you can test the URL that was supplied to see if it is treated as an external resource. Here, I split the string by whitespace, then tested each part to see if it is a defined URL.

```js
const string = `Here is a link https://www.somewebsite.com/ here is a link already in an a tag <a href="https://www.somewebsite.com/">https://www.somewebsite.com/</a>`;

const newString = string
  .split(/\s+/)
  .map(string => (isDefinedUrl(string)) ? makeUrl(string) : string)
  .join(' ');

console.log(newString);


function isDefinedUrl(possibleUrl) {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = possibleUrl;
  return (possibleUrl === a.href);
}

function makeUrl(url) {
  return `<a href="${url}">${url}</a>`;
}
```

Comment: That is a really clever approach!

Comment: very clever, but then you are stuck if a hyperlink is not surrounded with spaces, like `this link (https://example.com)`... What could be other valid separators?